# Python script write to file stopping after certain point

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to analyze a sqlite3 file and printing the results to a text file. If i test the code with print it all works fine. When i write it to a file it cuts out at the same point every time.

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
import time


conn = sqlite3.connect("History.sqlite")
curs = conn.cursor()
results = curs.execute("SELECT visits.id, visits.visit_time, urls.url, urls.visit_count \
                                        FROM visits INNER JOIN urls ON urls.id = visits.url \
                                        ORDER BY visits.id;")
exportfile = open('chrome_report.txt', 'w')


for row in results:
    timestamp = row[1]
    epoch_start = datetime.datetime(1601,1,1)
    delta = datetime.timedelta(microseconds=int(timestamp))
    fulltime = epoch_start + delta
    string = str(fulltime)
    timeprint = string[:19]
    exportfile.write("ID: " + str(row[0]) + "\t")
    exportfile.write("visit time: " + str(timeprint) + "\t")
    exportfile.write("Url: " + str(row[2]) + "\t")
    exportfile.write("Visit count: " + str(row[3]))
    exportfile.write("\n")
    print "ID: " + str(row[0]) + "\t"
    print "visit time: " + str(timeprint) + "\t"
    print "Url: " + str(row[2]) + "\t"
    print "Visit count: " + str(row[3])
    print "\n"   
conn.close()
```

So the print results give the proper result but the export to the file stops in the middle of a url.

Comment: I guess it is a problem with the string. But you really can build this logic in SQL and dump result into a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I would start by replacing the for loop with the one below

```
with open('chrome_report.txt', 'w') as exportfile:
    for row in results:
        try:
            timestamp = row[1]
            epoch_start = datetime.datetime(1601,1,1)
            delta = datetime.timedelta(microseconds=int(timestamp))
            fulltime = epoch_start + delta
            string = str(fulltime)
            timeprint = string[:19]
            exportfile.write("ID: " + str(row[0]) + "\t")
            exportfile.write("visit time: " + str(timeprint) + "\t")
            exportfile.write("Url: " + str(row[2]) + "\t")
            exportfile.write("Visit count: " + str(row[3]))
            exportfile.write("\n")
            print "ID: " + str(row[0]) + "\t"
            print "visit time: " + str(timeprint) + "\t"
            print "Url: " + str(row[2]) + "\t"
            print "Visit count: " + str(row[3])
            print "\n"
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
```

By using the "with" statement (context manager) we eliminate the need to close the file. By using the try/except we capture the error and print it. This will show you where your code is failing and why.

Comment: I discovered that closing the export file was the issue. I added exportfile.close() to my script and now it is working flawless. Thank you for your input, i didn't use the adapted script but i did get inspired by your answer.

Comment: did you use a context manager (the 'with' statement) for your solution?